# Trouble understanding 5 orientations of d orbitals

Tags: orbitals

I understand $d_{xy}$ and $d_{yz}$ and those orientations but ones like $d_{z^2}$ are very strange to me.

Can someone please explain that to me?

Comment: Does [this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19960/why-do-the-d-orbitals-have-these-notations) help?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! Yes. I wanted to add @Klaus's link too. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Generally speaking, and very informally (I'd get shredded if I put this an answer), you want all 3 planes and all 3 axes to have a double dumbbell in them.  This is not possible with 5 orbitals,  3 orbitals each put two dumbbells in the planes of coordinate system (xy,yz,xz). The remaining two have 4 dumbbells occupy 3 axes.  So 1 of the dumbbells 'folds up' into the donut shape.  This is just how the math works out.

Comment: And even shorter than Lighthart’s description: This is just how the maths works out.