# Why are the d-orbitals so named?

Tags: nomenclature, atoms, orbitals

Why are the $d$-orbitals so named?

The naming of $p$-orbitals is fine.
I can easily name any p orbital according to the axis along which it is oriented.
But what about $d$- orbitals?
Why are there subscripts such as $x^2-y^2$ and $z^2$ ?
Are we supposed to read it like "x squared- y squared"?

Also why does the $d_{z^2}$ orbital has a ring like structure around it?

Is there any order in why the degenerate d orbitals are filled? Like for $p$-orbitals we have an order of filling: $p_x$ then  $p_y$ then  $p_z$.(Not too sure of this.My friend told me about this.)

My friend also told me that for d-orbitals, $d_z$ is conventionally taken as the principal orbital.(Again not too sure what he meant by that).

Although I wouldn't want to get into knowing about f orbitals,but information on that might help someone looking for answers on that.

I wonder why this hasn't been asked on CSE before.

NB: I have visited this [link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19960/why-do-the-d-orbitals-have-these-notations) , but couldn't understand much.

Thank You.

Comment: That answer should have told you everything you needed to know already, so strictly speaking this is a duplicate. The whole point is, the $p_x$, $p_y$ and $p_z$ orbitals are so named because the corresponding wavefunctions are of a form $xf$, $yf$ and $zf$ respectively where $f$ is a function of the the coordinates $r, \theta, \phi$. The same thing can be said of the $d$ orbitals.

Comment: Well there is much more to the question than that.And also, I didn't understand much from that as stated in the question.I really don't have much knowledge on wavefunctions as well. :(

Comment: Exactly the same thing can be said of the $d$ orbitals. They are of the form $xyg$, $yzg$, ... where $g$ is also a function of $r, \theta, \phi$. Same goes for the $f$ orbitals. **There is no correct order for filling.** I could call the x-axis the y-axis, and I could call the y-axis the x-axis. That would make the $p_y$ orbital the $p_x$ orbital and vice versa. But obviously the molecule does not know which axis I have called which. Lastly, I have absolutely no idea what a principal orbital is, and I don't think that such a thing even exists.

Comment: The idea about wavefunctions is that each orbital is not a real object, it is a mathematical function obtained by solving the Schrodinger equation. The diagrams that you see are just graphs of these functions, just like how you can draw a graph for $f(x) = x^2$. It just so happens that the graph of $d_{z^2}$ has a ring. Of course before you are introduced to quantum mechanics, the way you view an orbital is like a container, but that is not really the case. Ultimately, there is no good way to explain the reason behind the naming of the orbitals without quantum mechanics.

Comment: Well that definitely helped.Thank you.You should go ahead and post this as an answer.

Comment: Technically, not even $\ce{p}_x$, $\ce{p}_y$ and $\ce{p}_z$ are accurate names, they *should* be called $\ce{p}_{-1}$, $\ce{p}_{+1}$ and $\ce{p}_{0}$. The first two are, in fact, complex orbitals (i.e. have a contribution with $i$ in it) and only their linear combinations gives us $\ce{p}_x$ and $\ce{p}_y$.

Comment: Of course, and so are the d orbitals, they are $\mathrm{d}_{-2}$, $\mathrm{d}_{-1}$, $\mathrm{d}_{0} (= \mathrm{d}_{z^2})$, $\mathrm{d}_{+1}$ and $\mathrm{d}_{+2}$. On top of that, I went back to check and it turns out that $f = f(r)$ and $g = g(r)$, i.e. they are independent of $\theta$ and $\phi$. And the $\mathrm{d}_{z^2}$ orbital is of the form $(3z^2-r^2)g(r)$, but apparently we just say $z^2$ because it is easier to say.