# Typography of atomic orbital subscripts p_x

Tags: notation

It the notation $\mathrm{p_x}$, $\mathrm{p_y}$ and $\mathrm{d_{x^2{-}y^2}}$, are the subscripts variables (and therefore should be in italics) or are they labels (labels for directions, I suppose, and therefore should be upright)?

Comment: The notation is for the subshells of electrons in atoms. The uses of x,y, and z correspond to the x,y and z axis in 3D space, and are therefore labels not variables.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Orbitals_table for the visualized shapes.

Comment: @Max you sure they should be upright? I thought they're used slanted-ly everywhere.

Comment: I'll defer to the ACS style guide -- italic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The subscripts that specify orbital axes are written in *italic*. This is mentioned in ACS style guide.$^{[1]}$ So for instance

$$\mathrm{d}_{x^2 - y^2}.$$

Be careful though. Other subscripts for orbitals are generally upright, *e.g.*,

$$\mathrm{t_{2g}}.$$

[$[1]$](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/bk-2006-STYG) Anne M. Coghill, Lorrin R. Garson. ($2006$). *The ACS Style Guide. Effective Communication of Scientific Information*. American Chemical Society. **DOI**: 10.1021/bk-2006-STYG, **ISBN**: 9780841239999 (print), 9780841228306 (online). (p 256)

Comment: I would say this contradicts the basic rule of labels being upright (and I consider an axis name a label), but there we go.

Comment: @mhchem It shouldn't contradict. Consider $\mathrm{p}_x$ for example. It specifies in which coordinate axis the $\mathrm{p}$-orbital is "directed". So if it is pointed along the $x$-axis, here $x$ varies and is not a constant.

Comment: I know this is nitpicking, but I would say x does not stand for a number, it does stand for a (fixed) direction. Or, putting it differently, x is a shorthand label for $x$-axis. It a label. It's a label of direction, just as "south" is. I don't see any 'placeholder of a value' property here.

Comment: @mhchem No, I don't think that is correct. It does not refer to the axis. It refers to a mathematical function which appears in the wavefunction corresponding to the orbital. There is no "x2-y2" axis. It just means that that d orbital has a x2-y2 term in its wavefunction.

Comment: The p orbitals just happen to be "(a whole bunch of other stuff) multiplied by one of (x, y, z)". The p_z orbital does indeed point along the z-axis but it is not named so because it points along that axis.

Comment: Yes, I believe @orthocresol is correct. The terms are still called *orbital axes* though AFAIK, but the analogy indeed only works for $(x, y, z)$. (Correct me if I am wrong.)

Comment: See also: [Why do the d orbitals have these notations?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19960/why-do-the-d-orbitals-have-these-notations)

Comment: My interpretation came from IUPAC's Green Book: "The overall rule is that ... labels, are roman. Sometimes there may seem to be doubt as to whether a symbol represents a quantity or has some other meaning (such as a label): a good role is that quantities, or variables, may have a range of numerical values, but labels cannot." However, they continue themselves with electric field strength in x direction as $E_x$. I would have said $x$ here (!) is a label, because it cannot take multiple values, but is just a label/name for a direction.

Comment: Another interesting find: ACS Style Guide reads "Use italic type for: ... axes: the *y* axis" (p. 212). (I understood that we have no axis labels here.)